# Blank Mail screen which then crashes but reminas open in background

Tags: mac

The title sums it up.
Once opened it simply doesn't show any emails and then eventually seems to crash but is open in the background still not showing anything.

Comment: What version of OS X? What model Mac? Did you try installing an unsupported version of OS X to this machine? Have you deleted any system files recently? Are you running any automator functions for mail? Do you have a time machine back up that you can restore your Mac to a time before the error. Have you tried a restart?

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your Mac and see if that fixes it.